# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property, in mysql.php using OOP PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Help I got this error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in D:\Installed
>   Programs\deshoppy with joomla\htdocs\ds\features\mysql.php on line 64

And below is mysql.php:

```
<?php
// Give access to db information
global $db_type;
global $db_host;
global $db_user;
global $db_pass;
global $db_name;

// Connecting database
$db=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
$db or die("Failed to connect database using $db_type :P");

// Selecting database
mysql_select_db($db_name) or
    die('Failed to select database :P');

// Non OOP Functions

function db_query($q){
    $qry=mysql_query($q);
    return $qry;
}

function db_fetch_array($qry){
    $qary=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    return $qary;
}

function db_num_rows($qry){
    $qrnr=mysql_num_rows($qry);
    return $qrnr;
}

function db_error(){
    $db_error=mysql_error();
    return $db_error;
}

function db_close(){
    $db_close=mysql_close();
    return $db_close;
}

// OOP

class aDatabase{


    public $hostname="";
    public $username="";
    public $password="";
    public $database="";

    public $query=""; // Last SQL code
    public $result=""; // Result of mysql_query
    public $fetch_array=""; // Result of mysql_fetch_array
    public $link=""; // Result of mysql_connect
    public $num_rows=""; // Result of mysql_num_rows
    public $error=""; // Result of mysql_error
    public $disconnect=""; // Result of mysql_close

    // Adding parameter to class
    public function __construct($par_host, $par_user, $par_pass, $par_db){
        $this->$hostname=$par_host;
        $this->$username=$par_user;
        $this->$password=$par_pass;
        $this->$database=$par_db;

    }

    // Connect to database
    function connect(){
        $this->$link = mysql_connect(
            $this->$hostname,
            $this->$username,
            $this->$password
        );

        return $this->$link;
    }

    // Fetch array
    function fetch_array(){
        $this->$fetch_array=mysql_fetch_array($this->$result);
        return $this->$fetch_array;
    }

    function num_rows(){
        $this->$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($this->$num_rows);
        return $this->$num_rows;
    }

    // May not accurate to last error
    function error(){
        $this->$error = mysql_error();
        return $this->$error;
    }

    function disconnect(){
        $this->$disconnect = mysql_close($this->$link);
        return $this->$disconnect;

        $this->$link="";
    }
}

// Proccess new database connection
$aDB=new aDatabase($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$aDB->connect();

// Clean database information to prevent hacking
$db_name="";
$db_user="";
$db_pass="";
$db_host="";

?>
```

And on ds_configuration.php (i'm forgot to tell this before):

```
<?php
// Site offline information
$site_offline=false;
$site_offline_title="Akdira";

// Database information
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="123456";
$db_name="deshoppy";
$db_host="localhost";
$db_type="mysql";

?>
```

Would you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Which is the 64th line?

Comment: OOP + globals is such a contradiction. The code is so oldschool PHP4,.. I suggest you to read up some PHP5 docs and the Zend code style guide. This will improve your project by about 6000%

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line top of your code: `global $db_host;` It's wrong. In PHP global variables must be declared `global` inside a function if they are going to be used in that function to get access global scope variables.

You should assign variables value before creating instance of class. 
You did not assign any value to your variables like `$db_host` and so on...

```
$db_host = "localhost";
//...
$aDB=new aDatabase($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Also try this in class variable members:

```
$this->hostname
```

Instead of:

```
$this->$hostname
     //^
```

In this case remove `$` sign in all class variable members by `$this`.

**Update:** As your last edition, to include `ds_configuration.php` within `mysql.php`:

```
include_once('ds_configuration.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "syntax" errors.

Instead of using

```
$this->$attribute
```

you should use

```
$this->attribute
```

**Why isn't it real syntax error?**

Because PHP lets you do things like this:

```
$var = 'attribute';
$this->$var;
```

which is the same that

```
$this->attribute
```

**Following this path...**

...you can for example invoke function taking it's name from a variable:

```
function funcName($nbr, $str) { /*...*/ }
$var = 'funcName';
$result = $var(1,'test');
```

Or the same with variables

```
$foo = 'bar';
$varName = 'foo';
echo $$varName;
```

is the same that

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo;
```